# ACF Flexible Content - Not showing anything when taking the data from author page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

The content doesn't want to display. I have read and went through the documentation many times. I even asked other developers to see and check the code, and it looked correct for them.

I need this to be on the Author page. I have tested this on a custom post type, a page etc... and it worked. However, this info must come from the author page.

Here are my fields:[image]

Here is where the fields are displayed: [image: The author page location]

And below is my code. It always displays nothing. Why is that? I have version 5.6.1

```

```
// check if the flexible content field has rows of data

if( have_rows('social_media') ):

     // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('social_media') ) : the_row();

        if( get_row_layout() == 'social_media_icons' ):

         echo   the_sub_field('media_facebook');

        endif;

    endwhile;

else :

    echo "nothing";// no layouts found

endif;

?>
```

```

Comment: try "social_media" insted of "social_media_icons" in while loop and also pass page id in have_rows as second argument

Comment: That didn't work either. I have tried that before as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

It's an Author page. There are many Authors and each of them is unique.

If we try to pull the field, and we have say 10authors, what field will it pull? A standard loop won't work here.

We need to pass the author id. user_1.

Now, that's static, we want it dynamic, so we can get the author id, and then concatinate it to the user_$id.

Such as:

```
 $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                if( have_rows('social_media','user_'. $author_id) ):

                    while ( have_rows('social_media', 'user_'. $author_id) ) : the_row();

                        if( get_row_layout() == 'social_media_icons' ): ?>


    <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php  endwhile;

                    else :
                        echo 'no content';
                    endif;


                endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

This will work, because the ID now is dynamic, and we are getting the current user ID and then concatenating it to the 'user_'.

That code there works 100% as of version 5.6.5, and should work in further as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$page_id = //your page id;

// check if the flexible content field has rows of data

if( have_rows('social_media',$page_id) ):

 // loop through the rows of data
 while ( have_rows('social_media',$page_id) ) : the_row($page_id);

    if( get_row_layout() == 'social_media_icons' ):

     echo   the_sub_field('media_facebook');

    endif;

 endwhile;

else :

echo "nothing";// no layouts found

endif;

?>
```

Comment: in which page you have defined acf field?

Comment: I tried many pages, well, I tried author page and page-contact.

Comment: I have defined the ACF field on the Author page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove echo from this line the_sub_field('media_facebook');

```
    // check if the flexible content field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('social_media') ):

         // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('social_media') ) : the_row();

            if( get_row_layout() == 'social_media_icons' ):

                the_sub_field('media_facebook');

            endif;

        endwhile;

    else :

        echo 'nothing'; // no layouts found

    endif;
```